# Как изменить заголовок приложения?

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, не могу никак изменить заголовок приложения. Сейчас в `ActionBar` отображается значок приложения и название `Activity`. Пробовал убирать в манифесте `android:label="@string/title_activity_main"` > тогда название `Activity` заменяется на `com.android.название_приложения`. А мне надо убрать и значок и название, чтобы вставлять свои элементы. Пробовал также `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` перед   `setContentView();`, но приложение висло и вылетало. Как можно убрать без изменения темы ?Или только возможно убрать `ActionBar` и вручную сделать верхнюю часть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кастомный лэйаут `ActionBar` делается так:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
if (actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.id.your_custom_layout);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
}
```

В зависимости от задачи, можно просто добавить кастомных экшнов, как это сделать:

[Action Items](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems)

[Styling](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Style)

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, это не такая уж и хорошая идея убирать эту строку с заголовокм. Может, всё-таки выставите нормальный заголовок и иконку?

Во-вторых, если уж так хочется удалить её, то да, вам нужна Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE. Если что-то падает и виснет, то значит вы делаете что-то не так или не тогда когда нужно. Либо виснет и падает совсем по другой причине. Вот на [SO эта тема](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991764).